# Three set problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a school of 120 students it was found out that 75 read English, 55 read science and 35 read biology. All the 120 students read at least one of three subject and 49 read exactly two subjects. How many students read all the three subjects?

I have spent all day but I couldn't solve it help me please!

Comment: I have spent all day but I couldn't solve it help me please!

Comment: Have you drawn a Venn diagram?

Comment: I have but I couldn't use it to solve it

Comment: Help me with the workings

Comment: $a + b + c = 120$, $a + 2b + 3c = 75 + 55 + 35$ and $b = 49$ imply $c = -2$, which seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, we must add up the number of students reading English, the number of students reading Science, and the number of students reading Biology. Then we must subtract this sum from the number of people reading English and Science, the number of people reading Science and Biology, and the number of students reading Biology and English. Finally, we must add back the number of students reading all three of the subjects; this calculates the number of students in the school. Let $x$ be the number of students reading all three of the subjects. We now have the equation

$75+55+35-49+x=120$

Solving for $x$ yields $\boxed{4}$ as the number of students reading all three of the subjects.

Comment: Can you break it down for me

Comment: Yes; so in the Venn Diagram, we have three intersecting circles right? We already know the number of students described in the diagram is $120.$ We want to set up an expression to help us find the middle part where all three circles intersect; call that $x.$ Now, we start by adding the sizes of each individual circle; don't worry about intersections. So we have $75+55+35.$ However, now we are counting the three intersection regions of two circles twice; we only want it once, so we subtract the collective size of those regions. The problem says this size is $49,$ so we subtract that.

Comment: Now, notice that we counted the region where all three circles are intersecting three times from just looking at the individual circles, but then subtracted this region three times when looking at the intersections of two circles. So, we want to add this part back in. Using all of this, we can set up the equation in my solution to solve for $x.$

Comment: But how did you count for those who read exactly two subject (49)

Comment: Well, the problem does not explicitly tell you how many people are specifically reading two subjects, it only tells you the sum of them ("...$49$ read exactly two subjects."). Fortunately, we only care about the sum, so we just use $49.$

Comment: What of the uses of formula. Because the lecturer demands the use of formula

Comment: What is the formula you are referring to?

Comment: If you are referring to the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, for this problem, there are three sets, so we have $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|B\cap C|-|C\cap A|+|A\cap B\cap C|.$

Comment: I used your formula but I got different answer

Comment: I got X=2 which is different from yours

Comment: The union part should be equal to the size of the school, $120.$ The size of the individual sets should be $75,55,$ and $35.$ In addition, the collective size of the intersections of two sets is $49,$ as we discussed. We don't know the size of the intersections of three sets, so we set $x.$ Computational errors may be possible, so be careful when solving for $x.$ $120=75+55+35-49+x \implies 120=165-49+x \implies 120=116+x \implies 4=x \implies x=4,$ and we are finished.

Comment: OK....then this question doesn't work with the principle of inclusion exclusion. Because that is what I used and I had different answer

Comment: This question definitely works with the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, you just have to be careful when applying it. What did you do to get $x=2?$

Comment: I think this calculation is not correct: the number of elements in exactly two of $A$, $B$ and $C$ is not $|A \cap B| + |B \cap C| + |C \cap A|$ but $|A \cap B| + |B \cap C| + |C \cap A| - 3|A \cap B \cap C|$.